# Having Trouble with ObjectInputStream/OutputStream

Tags: serialization, dictionary, arraylist, objectinputstream

I am having trouble with my programs ability to save my Maps to a file. Here are my two methods for writing and reading my maps and arraylist.

Here is my read method:

```
private void getData() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    File f_Instructors = new File(PSLTrackerInfo.file + "instructors.brent");
    File f_Students = new File(PSLTrackerInfo.file + "students.brent");
    File f_Times = new File(PSLTrackerInfo.file + "times.brent");
    if (f_Instructors.exists()) {
        try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new 
                BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f_Instructors)))) {
            //Add theList back in
            if (in.readObject() != null) {
                TreeMap<Instructor, Set<Student>> read = null;
                while(in.available() > 0) {
                    read = (TreeMap<Instructor, Set<Student>>) 
                            in.readObject();
                }
                if (read != null) {
                    for (Instructor key : read.keySet()) {
                        System.out.println(key);
                        Set<Student> values = read.get(key);
                        PSLTrackerInfo.addInstructor(key, values);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Instructors Found! Reading...");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No instructor data saved.1");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No instructor data saved.2");
            }
            in.close();
        }
    }
    //Add times back in
    if (f_Times.exists()) {
        try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new 
                BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f_Times)))) {
            if (in.readObject() != null) {
                TreeMap<Student, ArrayList<Date>> readTimes = null;
                while(in.available() > 0) {
                    readTimes = (TreeMap<Student, ArrayList<Date>>) in.readObject();
                }
                if (readTimes != null) {
                    for (Student key : readTimes.keySet()) {
                        System.out.println(key);
                        ArrayList<Date> values = readTimes.get(key);
                        PSLTrackerInfo.addTimes(key, values);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Dates Found! Reading...");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("No dates saved.");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("No dates saved.");
            }
            in.close();
        }
    }
    //Add newStudents back in
    if (f_Students.exists()) {
        try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new 
                BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f_Students)))) {
            if (in.readObject() != null) {
                ArrayList<Student> readStudents = null;
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    readStudents = (ArrayList<Student>) in.readObject();

                }
                if (readStudents != null) {
                    PSLTrackerInfo.setTheList(readStudents);
                }
                System.out.println("New students found! Reading...");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No new students data saved.");
            }
            in.close();
        }
    }
}
```

And Here is my Writing method:

```
    private void saveData() {
    System.out.println("Saving Data...");
    File f_Instructors = new File(PSLTrackerInfo.file + "instructors.brent");
    File f_Students = new File(PSLTrackerInfo.file + "students.brent");
    File f_Times = new File(PSLTrackerInfo.file + "times.brent");
    ObjectOutputStream out_Instructors = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out_Students = null;
    ObjectOutputStream out_Times = null;
    try {
        out_Instructors = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
                BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f_Instructors)));
        out_Students = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
                BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f_Students)));
        out_Times = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
                BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f_Times)));
        out_Instructors.writeObject(PSLTrackerInfo.getMap());
        out_Times.writeObject(PSLTrackerInfo.getTimes());
        out_Students.writeObject(PSLTrackerInfo.getList());
        out_Instructors.flush();
        out_Students.flush();
        out_Times.flush();
        out_Instructors.close();
        out_Students.close();
        out_Times.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PrivateLessonsTrackerGUI.class.getName())
                .log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Sorry if it is a little confusing I have 3 files to save 3 different objects, if there is a way to save it into one file let me know but I just was getting a lot of errors that I couldn't figure out how to solve so this is what I ended up doing. Thanks for any help given.

To EJP: I tried this

```
TreeMap<Instructor, Set<Student>> read = null;
try {
    read = (TreeMap<Instructor, Set<Student>>) 
            in.readObject();
} catch (EOFException e) {
    System.out.println("Caught EOFException!");
}
```

And even when there was data in it when it was written to the file, I got an EOFException everytime.

Answer (score 0):

1. `readObject()` doesn't return null unless you wrote a null. If you're using that as a test for end of stream, it is invalid. The correct technique is to catch `EOFException`.
2. You are calling it and throwing away the result if it isn't null, and then calling it again. The second call *will* throw `EOFException` if there isn't another object in the file. It won't give you the same result as the first call. It's a stream.
3. `available()` is also not a valid test for end of stream. That's not what it's for. See the Javadoc. Again, the correct technique with `readObject()` is to catch `EOFException`.

Comment: I added my try/catch block but everytime I run I just keep getting the exception even with data in the map when I wrote it to the file.

Comment: I gave you about six things to fix, not just try/catch blocks. You need to address them *all.* The new code in your edit doesn't show any sign of it.